# Jensen-like Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I have the following question:

Suppose we have a function $g:\mathbb{Z}_+ \cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with the property, $g(\lfloor \frac{x+y}{2} \rfloor)$ + $g(\lceil \frac{x+y}{2} \rceil) \leq g(x) + g(y)$. $N$ is Geometrically distributed with parameter $p$. Also, $\mathbb{E}\{ g(N^2) \} < \infty$. $\{X(n)\}_0^\infty$ is $i.i.d.$ with $\mathbb{E}\{ g(X(0)^2) \} < \infty$. $N$ and $\{X(n)\}_0^\infty$ are mutually independent.

Then, does it follow that $\mathbb{E}\{ g( \sum_{n=0}^N X(n)) \} < \infty$? Do we need any other assumptions on $g(\cdot)$?